# How can I filter data comparing 2 JSON's and to save the result in an array

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, swift4

I need to extract all Posts Titles from an JSON API using another JSON API of users and after that to extract the count of comments for each Post.
Here I have:

1. API for USERS: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
2. API for POSTS: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
3. API for COMMENTS: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

In Users I have a unique ID, in Posts I have UserID and in comments I have PostID.

For the moment I extracted all data from all 3 API's in 3 arrays.
Now I need to create 2 functions:

- getPostsTitleForSelectedUser()
- getNumberOfCommentsForEachPost()

Here is a part of code:

```
    class UserDetailsController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailsTableView: UITableView!


    var usersArray = [User]()
    var postsArray = [Post]()
    var commentsArray = [Comment]()



    func getPostsTitleForSelectedUser() -> String{

        let postTitle: String? = "POST TITLE FOR TEST"
        return postTitle!
    }

    func getNumberOfCommentsForEachPost() -> String{

        let comments = "4131231231"
        return comments
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you using a table view if there can only be one cell?

Comment: But I use a Custom Cell in my table view. I have only 1 row in my table view and in that row I have a Custom Cell.

Comment: But it's pointless to use a table view for one cell. Just create a view (very similar to your cell) and show that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
func getPostsTitleForSelectedUser(user: User) -> [String] {
    return postsArray.filter { (post) -> Bool in
        post.userId == user.id
        }.map { (post) -> String in
            return post.title
    }
}

func getNumberOfCommentsForEachPost(post: Post) -> Int {
    return commentsArray.filter { (comment) -> Bool in
        comment.postId == post.id
    }.count
}
```